# Display Popular today,month,all content

Tags: drupal-7

i'm using drupal7 and can't figure out how to display Todays/Month/All popular content in side bar.people suggest use Statistics module but only filter Todays most popular content.i think it can be done with Views module. help me. many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Views + Blocks + Statistics. The key here is to sort and filter based on the content statistics.

You configure sorting using the **Field Settings** section of the view's admin screen. You configure filtering from the **Exposed Filters** section of the same admin screen.

As for displaying it in a "side bar" (block in Drupal-speak); you need to create a **Block** display type from your view's admin screen.